# How to have three regexes? Lua

Tags: lua

So, I have a project that requires lots of string manipulation. I want to match three strings in a main string by matching all the text inside a square bracket. Except this outputs 'c' as nil? Any help?

```
a,b,c = x:match("%[(%a+)%],%[(%a+)%]")
print(c)
print(b)
if vars[b] == vars[tc] then
    print(vars[b])
end
```

Comment: Please insert a clear input and output.

Comment: INPUT: *DISPLAY[AL][DL], [XX]
OUTPUT: nil
(a = AL
b = DL
c = nil)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one pattern:

```
x=[[
 *DISPLAY[AL][DL], [XX] 
]]
a,b,c = x:match("%[(%a+)%]%[(%a+)%], %[(%a+)%]")
print(a,b,c)
```